# C3861 'DbgRaiseAssertionFailure': identifier not found

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2013

I am using Windows 10 machine and using Visual Studio 2013 compiler. As mentioned in [error C3861: identifier not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575949/error-c3861-identifier-not-found),
the path $(WindowsSdk_71A_IncludePath) has been included in project.

Comment: You are gong to have to give us more information.

Comment: Make sure winnt.h gets #include'd, usually via `#include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dxiv gave the answer. Thank you.

`#include <windows.h>`